# Get help in constructing a pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python. I have a list of items, sth like this:

```
places = ['Alabama', 'Auburn', 'Jacksonville', 'Arizona', 'Flagstaff', 'Phoenix']
```

Please note that Auburn and Jacksonville are cities in Alabama state, whereas Flagstaff and Phoenix are cities in Arizona.

I need to create  a pandas data frame with two columns `['State','City']` like the following:

```
    State |    City
  --------|----------
 Alabama  | Auburn
 Alabama  | Jacksonville
 Arizona  | Flagstaff
 Arizona  | Phoenix
```

I was trying to create a dictionary, which has 'state' as the keys and the 'cities' as the values for the corresponding keys. But it is not working for me, since my knowledge is limited in Pythoin right now.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hello Sir, my idea was to define a empty dictionary initially. then add the keys to it as the states. But, I am not very sure how to add keys, because I am looping over the list. thats the idea I have. I am trying to automate it.

Comment: Hello Sir, I made two different series, one for states and other for cities. But I can't merge them or concat them, since they are of different lengths. Any ideas will be really helpful. thanks

Comment: @jayant, are you states always followed by the same numbers of cities? For instance, is it always 1 state then 2 cities?

Comment: And how do you know that *Jacksonville* item does not belong to *Florida*. Many cases like that may show up down the chain like *Springfield*, *Washington*, *Greenville*, etc. Maybe show us how list is derived?

Comment: Hello colleagues, I think we can find the data at the link;

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_college_towns#College_towns_in_the_United_States

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys in a dictionary have to be unique, so you would be overwriting some of the values if you did something where one state has multiple cities;

```
In [1]: {'Arizona': 'Flagstaff', 'Arizona': 'Phoenix'}
Out[1]: {'Arizona': 'Phoenix'}
```

On the other hand, if you know that your keys are unique, `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict` does the job.

In your case, you could pass the information as a list of pairs.

```
In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame([['Arizona', 'Flagstaff'], ['Arizona', 'Phoenix'], ['Alabama', 'Auburn']], columns=['State', 'City'])

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
     State       City
0  Arizona  Flagstaff
1  Arizona    Phoenix
2  Alabama     Auburn
```

If you want to get rid of the redundant information that you are passing by including the state more than once, you could do something like

```
In [33]: cities = {'Alabama': ['Auburn', 'Jacksonville'], 'Arizona': ['Flagstaff', 'Phoenix']}

In [34]: pd.DataFrame(((k, c) for (k, v) in cities.items() for c in v), columns=['State', 'City'])
Out[34]: 
     State          City
0  Arizona     Flagstaff
1  Arizona       Phoenix
2  Alabama        Auburn
3  Alabama  Jacksonville
```

Comment: Hello Sir,I highly appreciate that you took time to answer my doubt. But actually, I do not have a nice list of tuples. What I have is  a huge list of states and its cities mixed together. For example: state1 followed by all its cities, then state2 followed by its cities and so on. So, I was wondering, if  want to use the above idea, will it be possible? your response is greatly appareciated.

Comment: Hello fuglede,, actually after some hard thinking I was able to figure it out, I converted it to a dictionary using  a 'for' loop and then I used your second idea. It proved to be very helpful. I can't be grateful to you enough.

Comment: You're welcome. :) You may want to accept the answer if you found it useful.